# Python Type Error: Series.name must be a hashable

Tags: pandas, hash, pandas-groupby, typeerror, pandas-apply

I have a grouped dataset (by `groupby`) called `level_temp_grouped` and I want to apply a function to two boolean columns namely, `up` and `fill_cand`, for each group.

```
level_temp['neighbor'] = level_temp_grouped[['up','fill_cand']].apply(lambda n: neighbor_fill(np.array(n)[:,0], np.array(n)[:,1]))
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

What is the problem?

level_temp is a pandas dataframe. Dp is the serial number of the observations I want to groupby as the data includes different observations of the same product in different times.

```
level_temp_grouped=level_temp.groupby('dp')
```

Full stack trace is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1274             try:
-> 1275                 result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1276             except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
   1310 
-> 1311         return self._wrap_applied_output(
   1312             data, keys, values, not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _wrap_applied_output(self, data, keys, values, not_indexed_same)
   1166             #  after raising AttributeError above
-> 1167             return self.obj._constructor_sliced(
   1168                 values, index=key_index, name=self._selection

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    352 
--> 353             name = ibase.maybe_extract_name(name, data, type(self))
    354 

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in maybe_extract_name(name, obj, cls)
   6391     if not is_hashable(name):
-> 6392         raise TypeError(f"{cls.__name__}.name must be a hashable type")
   6393 

TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10940/1897168105.py in <module>
      1 #level_temp_grouped[['up','fill_cand']].apply(lambda n: neighbor_fill(np.array(n)[:,0], np.array(n)[:,1]))
----> 2 level_temp_grouped[['up','fill_cand']].apply(lambda n: neighbor_fill(np.array(n)[:,0], np.array(n)[:,1]))

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1284 
   1285                 with group_selection_context(self):
-> 1286                     return self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1287 
   1288         return result

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f, data)
   1309         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
   1310 
-> 1311         return self._wrap_applied_output(
   1312             data, keys, values, not_indexed_same=mutated or self.mutated
   1313         )

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _wrap_applied_output(self, data, keys, values, not_indexed_same)
   1165             # TODO: sure this is right?  we used to do this
   1166             #  after raising AttributeError above
-> 1167             return self.obj._constructor_sliced(
   1168                 values, index=key_index, name=self._selection
   1169             )

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    351         else:
    352 
--> 353             name = ibase.maybe_extract_name(name, data, type(self))
    354 
    355             if is_empty_data(data) and dtype is None:

~\Anaconda3\envs\linde1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in maybe_extract_name(name, obj, cls)
   6390     # GH#29069
   6391     if not is_hashable(name):
-> 6392         raise TypeError(f"{cls.__name__}.name must be a hashable type")
   6393 
   6394     return name

TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

Comment: Will you please show the full stack trace? Also what is `level_temp_grouped`?